# XPS 13 with a USB C dock using two 34" 4k monitors - after connecting second montor the XPS and first go blank

Tags: xps, multiple-monitors, 4k-monitor

Ok, I have been at this for a while and tried every tip I could find and I am still struggling. Although I have not found an article that was 100% my issue so that might be why nothing has worked so far =*)

The setup: XPS 13 i7 xPro 8th Gen 16gb of mem Intel UHD 620 with a Startech dual DP dock (USB C) and two 34" curved 4k Dell monitors. Ubuntu 18.04 TLS. Using Ubuntu Desktop although I did try Plasma and had the same issue.

The problem: When I connect the dock with 1 monitor everything is fine. When I plug in the second monitor the XPS screen and the second monitor go black and the third turns on. If I then disconnect the third only the first monitor turns on and if I open settings devices displays the XPS screen has no config. If I set a resolution and choose to extend the displays the XPS screen turns on again. If I connect both monitors to the dock and then connect to the XPS only monitor 3 turns on and then the same procedure stands to get the XPS screen back on.

Lastly I should mention that the screens just go blank and Ubuntu thinks they are there. If I launch something it pops up on one of the blanked monitors and mouse can leave the third screen.

I have tried three different docks from Dell and Startech with the same behavior.

If anyone has any ideas I'd be greatful for some fresh eyes.

Thanks!